# 503 when trying to access boto3 from kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, boto3

I wrote a python script to automatically download a file from a DB and upload it to an S3 account we own. The script works from the PC and I'm successfully pinging Amazon S3 from within the Kubernetees we are working on, but I'm getting 503 when the script tries to upload/download a file from the S3. I'm using the following installation: 'python3.6 -m pip install boto3'
and getting the following error:  "otocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (503) when calling the GetObject operation (reached max retries: 15): Service Unavailable"
I tried adding/removing SSL, changing timeout and max retries, and nothing seems to help. Also tried different boto3 objects (client, session etc.)
The code that crashes is the following: (the line that crashes is the one marked with **)

```
def write_to_s3():
  s3 = get_s3()
  object1 = s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, FILENAME)
  print(object1)
  **test = object1.get()**
  latest_num = int(str(object1.get()['Body'].read())[2:-1])
  print(str(latest_num))
  ...

def get_s3():
    my_config = Config(
    region_name=REGION,
    connect_timeout=25,
    retries={
        'max_attempts': 15,
        'mode': 'standard'
    }
)
return boto3.resource('s3', use_ssl=False, config=my_config, aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get("ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
                      aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get("SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))
```

I really do not understand why this happens and found no answers or similar errors on the web. Please help!

Comment: what's `get_s3`?

Comment: are you able to `ssh` to the target machine(where your python script fail) and do some experiments?